# Is there a way to call DataWeave from a Java project not running on Mule?

Tags: dataweave

I am building a spring boot application and want to use DataWeave to do some transformations on JSON as part of the application.

Is there a way to reference DataWeave libraries in Spring Boot application for payload transformations?

I have looked up on google and could not find any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use this example

```
package example;

import org.mule.weave.v2.runtime.DataWeaveScript;
import org.mule.weave.v2.runtime.DataWeaveScriptingEngine;
import org.mule.weave.v2.runtime.ScriptingBindings;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class WeaveScriptingEngineExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataWeaveScriptingEngine scriptingEngine = new DataWeaveScriptingEngine();
    DataWeaveScript compile = scriptingEngine.compile("payload.a", new String[]{"payload"});
    compile.write(new ScriptingBindings().addBinding("payload", "{}", "application/json", new HashMap<>()));
  }

}
```

As a starting point for using DW directly from java.

For this to work you need the `org.mule.weave:runtime` and then all the modules that you want to have support. `org.mule.weave:core-modules` adds the most common modules such as xml, json, csv, multipart, text plain, binary and then other modules such as yaml, java, json lines, have there own module. By just adding them to your project classpath is enough for the runtime to discover it.

Comment: thanks for the code...

to run it outside of mule, which maven dependency will be required?

will it be this one?


`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mule.weave/java-module --<dependency><groupId>org.mule.weave</groupId><artifactId>java-module</artifactId><version>2.6.0-20230123</version</dependency>`

Comment: here is a sample spring-boot project

https://github.com/qureshii/springboot-dataweave